# How to extract tables from Excel worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to extract table from Excel worksheet (table is present in the worksheet) according to this tutorial: https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling-blog/spreadsheet/python/pandas/openpyxl/2020/05/19/Access-Tables-In-Excel.html

My Excel worksheet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xic8s.png)

My code:

```
import openpyxl


workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_excel.xlsx')
my_worksheet = workbook['my_worksheet']
print(my_worksheet._tables)
print(my_worksheet.tables.items())
```

Unfortunately I receive an error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'tables'
  File "C:\Users\user\TRAINING\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(my_worksheet.tables)
```

However my_worksheet._tables gives me a list of all tables in the worksheet where my table is included:

```
[<openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table object>
Parameters:
id=1, name='Table1', displayName='Table1', comment=None, ref='A1:C3', tableType=None, headerRowCount=1, insertRow=None, insertRowShift=None, totalsRowCount=None, totalsRowShown=False, published=None, headerRowDxfId=None, dataDxfId=None, totalsRowDxfId=None, headerRowBorderDxfId=None, tableBorderDxfId=None, totalsRowBorderDxfId=None, headerRowCellStyle=None, dataCellStyle=None, totalsRowCellStyle=None, connectionId=None, autoFilter=<openpyxl.worksheet.filters.AutoFilter object>
Parameters:
ref='A1:C3', filterColumn=[], sortState=None, sortState=None, tableColumns=[<openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableColumn object>
Parameters:
id=1, uniqueName=None, name='A', totalsRowFunction=None, totalsRowLabel=None, queryTableFieldId=None, headerRowDxfId=None, dataDxfId=None, totalsRowDxfId=None, headerRowCellStyle=None, dataCellStyle=None, totalsRowCellStyle=None, calculatedColumnFormula=None, totalsRowFormula=None, xmlColumnPr=None, extLst=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableColumn object>
Parameters:
id=2, uniqueName=None, name='B', totalsRowFunction=None, totalsRowLabel=None, queryTableFieldId=None, headerRowDxfId=None, dataDxfId=None, totalsRowDxfId=None, headerRowCellStyle=None, dataCellStyle=None, totalsRowCellStyle=None, calculatedColumnFormula=None, totalsRowFormula=None, xmlColumnPr=None, extLst=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableColumn object>
Parameters:
id=3, uniqueName=None, name='C', totalsRowFunction=None, totalsRowLabel=None, queryTableFieldId=None, headerRowDxfId=None, dataDxfId=None, totalsRowDxfId=None, headerRowCellStyle=None, dataCellStyle=None, totalsRowCellStyle=None, calculatedColumnFormula=None, totalsRowFormula=None, xmlColumnPr=None, extLst=None], tableStyleInfo=<openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo object>
Parameters:
name='TableStyleMedium9', showFirstColumn=False, showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=False]
```

Do you know what may be the reason? I found a simmilar issue on the other website but without the answer.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp

Comment: @Zenith_1024 this is not even a partial answer for my question. The problem is not connected with items() but with tables. Please, read next posts more carefully.

Comment: We wouldn't expect the error even if your sheet was totally empty since 'tables' should always be an attribute of a worksheet object. You can do a **print(dir(my_worksheet))** to see. However first would say ensure that your openpyxl is the latest release which is currently 3.0.10. Is the Traceback posted the complete error, probably is but just in case there is more details provided please add to the question. Using an IDE? Have you tried running from just a command line?

Comment: @moken Thank you for the answer. It looks as if the outdated openpyxl version was the reason. I was using 3.0.3 till now and with this version installed, print(dir(my_worksheet)) does not show tables in attributes, however since I updated to 3.0.10 everything has been alright. Thank you